# In sql I want to decrease all the values of a column in a table through a statement

Tags: sql

How would I write a statement to decrease all the values of a column in a table by 5?

would it be something like...

```
UPDATE table
MODIFY (column -5);
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as

```
UPDATE yourTable SET yourColumn = yourColumn - 5;
```

Comment: Perhaps because you have value instead of column as target for assignment?

Comment: @jarlh this was just to show the proper syntax.. I highly doubt *column* is the real name of his column anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
Update [TableName] Set [ColumnName] = [ColumnName] - 5
```